# Loading Array of string in Hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load following data in hive table

[data which i am loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d19hQ.jpg)

I used following table defination

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YOUTUBE_DATA (
VIDEO_ID    STRING,
UPLOADER    STRING,
INTERVAL    INT,
CATEGORY    STRING,
VIDEO_LEN   INT,
VIEW_NO     INT,
RATING      FLOAT,
NO_COMMENTS INT,
RELATED_VIDEOS  ARRAY
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/five';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/DATA/YOUTUBEDATA' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE YOUTUBE_DATA;

on running the query select * from youtube_data limit 10;
 following was output.

[output of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjiAV.jpg)

can anyone please help with mistake which I am doing and with solution ??

Comment: If you want to access array element , instead of using `select *` , use column names and for array column use index , example  `select video_id,interval,......,related_videos[0] from youtube_data;`

Comment: this is the output  QuRYeRnAuXM EvilSquirrelPictures 1135 Pets & Animals 252 1075 4.96 46 86
only the square bracket was removed

Comment: thanks for the help there was mistake in table design